# Спарсить значение из html текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, синтаксический-анализ

Я в регулярках полный нуб. Помогите спарсить значение из html текста:

```
<span style="cursor:pointer" class="sw1" onclick="document.location='/logout'" onmouseover="hint('<center>До конца действия: 237 д. 0 ч.</center>', this, 75,125)"></span>
```

Мне нужно спарсить данные: **До конца действия: 237 д. 0 ч.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = "hint('<center>До конца действия: 237 д. 0 ч.</center>', this, 75,125)";
$first = preg_replace('/.*\<center>/', '', $var);
$second = preg_replace('/<\/center\>.*/', '', $first);
print("$second"); // До конца действия: 237 д. 0 ч.
```

Comment: @--A

    print("$second");

Попахивает индусятиной.

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = <<<EOD
<span style="cursor:pointer" class="sw1" onclick="document.location='/logout'" onmouseover="hint('<center>До конца действия: 237 д. 0 ч.</center>', this, 75,125)"></span>
EOD;

if (preg_match('#<center>(?P<result>.*?)</center>#', $content, $matches)) {
  echo $matches['result'];
}
```

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/ztIJP2).

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "<center>До конца действия: 237 д. 0 ч.</center>";
preg_match('|(\d+?) д. (\d{1,2}) ч.|', $var, $match);
echo $match[0];
```